# gdb : What is the call to "test" in the disassembled code?

Tags: gdb, disassembly

When reviewing the disassembled code within gdb, there is a line

```
 test   %r13,%r13
```

But there isn't any reference to "test" in the code.

```
   0x00002b514569f56f <+95>:    cmpq   $0x0,0x8(%rbx)
   0x00002b514569f574 <+100>:   mov    %rbx,-0x70(%rbp)
   0x00002b514569f578 <+104>:   movq   $0x0,-0x68(%rbp)
   0x00002b514569f580 <+112>:   je     0x2b514569f58b <myTest+123>
   0x00002b514569f582 <+114>:   lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rdi
   0x00002b514569f586 <+118>:   callq  0x2b514591bf90 <_ZN25WeakPreserve>
   0x00002b514569f58b <+123>:   nop
   0x00002b514569f58c <+124>:   test   %r13,%r13
=> 0x00002b514569f58f <+127>:   mov    (%r15),%r14
   0x00002b514569f592 <+130>:   je     0x2b514569f700 <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+496>
   0x00002b514569f598 <+136>:   mov    0x0(%r13),%r13
   0x00002b514569f59c <+140>:   test   %r12d,%r12d
   0x00002b514569f59f <+143>:   js     0x2b514569f638 <
```

What does this "test" pertain to and since it appears a few times, does it always mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)) is an assembly instruction, just like the je,lea,callq,mov instructions that you also see

Comment: Thanks for the link.